# Is there a shorter way in ANTLR to specify optional repeating elements?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

When defining grammars I find myself writing this pattern quite often:

`expr4: expr1 expr2 expr3 (',' expr1 expr2 expr3)*`

Is there a more concise way to express it, without redundancy?
Of course I could define something like:

`expr5: expr1 expr2 expr3`

but I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, besides the `expr5 : expr1 expr2 expr3;` (and then doing `expr4 : expr5 (‘,’ expr5)*;`, there is no other way.